# Python extract email address from a HUGE string

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have been using this:
(I know, there are probably more efficient ways...)

Given this in an email message:

```
Submitted data:
First Name: MyName
Your Email Address: email@domain.com
TAG:
```

I coded this:

```
intStart = (bodystring.rfind('First ')) + 12
intEnd = (bodystring.rfind('Your Email'))
receiver_name = bodystring[intStart:intEnd]

intStart = (bodystring.rfind('Your Email Address: ')) + 20
intEnd = (bodystring.rfind('TAG:'))
receiver_email = bodystring[intStart:intEnd]
```

... and got what I needed. This worked because I had the `'TAG'` label.

Now I am given this:

```
Submitted data:
First name: MyName
Last name:
Email: email@domain.com
```

I'm having a brain block on getting the email address without a next word. There is whitespace. Can someone nudge me in the right direction? I suspect I can dig out the email address after the occurrence of `'Email:'` using regex...

Comment: If your input is always in this structure, you can split on spaces and grab the last item. `bodystring.split(' ')[-1]`

Comment: "There is whitespace" - wait, does that mean you have another whitespace _after_ the email address, but _not_ another word ?

Comment: Because if that's the case, @C_Z_ is wrong

Comment: Is the formatting correct? Is the data actually split into lines like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can, in fact, make use of RegEx to extract e-mails.

- To find single e-mails in a text, you can make use of
  `re.search().group()`
- In case you want to find multiple emails, you can make use of
  `re.findall()`

An example

```
    import re
    text = "First name: MyName Last name: Email: email@domain.com "
    
    email = re.search(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", text)
    print(email.group())
    
    emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", text)
    print (emails)
```

This would give the output as

```
email@domain.com
['email@domain.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching for strings is often better done with splitting, and occasionally regular expressions. So first split the lines:

```
bodylines = bodystring.splitlines()
```

Split the resulting lines on the `:` delimiter (make a generator):

```
chunks = (line.split(':') for line in bodylines)
```

Now grab the first one that has "email" on the left and `@` on the right:

```
address = next(val.strip() for key, val in chunks if 'email' in key.lower() and '@' in val)
```

If you want all the emails across multiple lines, replace `next` with a list comprehension:

```
addresses = [val.strip() for key, val in chunks if 'email' in key.lower() and '@' in val]
```

This can be done in one line with no imports (if you replace `chunks` with its definition, not that I recommend it). Regex are a much heavier tool that allow you to specify much more general patterns, but are also much slower as a result. If you can get away with simple and effective tools, do it: don't bring in the sledgehammer until you need it!

Answer (score 1):

If the email should come after the word Email followed by a `:`, you could match the Name part, and capture the email in a group with an email like pattern.

```
\bEmail[^:]*:\s*([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)
```

- `\bEmail` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, match `Email`
- `[^:]*:\s*` Match optional chars other than `:`, then match `:` and optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+` Match a single `@` between 1+ more non whitespace chars ecluding the `@` itself
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IWW8BM/1)

Example with re.findall that returns the values  of the capture groups:

```
import re
 
regex = r"\bEmail[^:]*:\s*([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)"
 
s = ("Submitted data:\n"
    "First Name: MyName\n"
    "Your Email Address: email@domain.com\n"
    "TAG:\n\n"
    "Submitted data:\n"
    "First name: MyName\n"
    "Last name:\n"
    "Email: email@domain.com")
 
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['email@domain.com', 'email@domain.com']
```